# Chrome extension message passing from popup to content

Tags: google-chrome-extension, callback

I'm trying to create a chrome extension to learn front-end technologies, and got stuck on message passing between popup and content script.

The following is what I'm trying to do: 
 1. Let background page hold a global var. 
 2. When user clicking a button on the popup html, the global var is modified. Meanwhile, the popup sends the global var to the content scripts for all of the tabs.

In the background.js I have:

```
var settings = {
    version: 1,
    enabled: false
};
```

popup.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#switcher").click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
        var settings = bg.settings;
        settings.enabled = !settings.enabled;

        // send message to the content for all the tabs
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function (tabs) {
            for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; ++i) {
                console.log("sending message to tab " + i);
                chrome.runtime.sendMessage(tabs[i].id, {enabled: settings.enabled}, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, the content.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            console.log("request is: " + request.enabled);

            sendResponse("get it");
        }
    );
});
```

I tried to debug it, but I found the 'sendMessage' function never got returned back.. and the 'onMessage' never got triggered. Did I miss something?

My manifest file:

```
{
    "name": "__MSG_appName__",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus", "storage", "tabs"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "scripts/background.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "images/icon-19.png",
            "38": "images/icon-38.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at":"document_start",
            "all_frames":true,
            "matches": ["*://*/*"],
            "js": ["bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "scripts/content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": ["bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map"]
}
```

Comment: For future reference: you should right-click your extension's button and select Inspect Popup to try and debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) instead of [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) to send messages to content scripts in tabs.